# php Escape all characters before comparing

Tags: php, tags, escaping

I need some effective way to escape all special characters in string.For example, my string

```
I need some effective way(1) [2] for $10 + e
```

should be converted in

```
I need some effective way\(1\) \[2\] for \$10 \+ e
```

thx

Comment: have you tried using the escape/addslashes function?

Comment: [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)

Comment: addslahes only handles single quote, double quote, backslash and NUL bytes. He seems to be escaping anything that's non-alphanum or space.

Comment: @savinger add slashes isn't what milos wants.

Comment: What special characters do you want escaped? Usually one escapes special characters for transportation, like SQL-queries or URL's. The set of special characters therefore depends on the environment, the string will be interpreted in. There are many predefined escaping functions in php like `mysql_real_escape_string` and `rawurlencode`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `quotemeta`:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.quotemeta.php

Comment: Obviously need to be careful what context this is being used in though - not a good idea to use for escaping for database or shell arguments. There's much better ways to both those things.

Comment: This is what i was looking for. I hope it will work :) Thx mate